# I want to create a manual for a web app using asp.net core. What is the best way to do it?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I am doing a internship and my company asked me to create a web manual for their web application.
Apparently they just want me to create the site and add an admin panel so they can add the text part themselves.

What is the best way to go about it?
Like should I use MVC or Razor? or can someone give me something I can use as reference code-wise since I can't inspect the actual code when the site is made with asp.net.

[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBuGd.png)

btw, I just watched a 1 hour asp.net core video on youtube so my knowledge is very limited on it

Comment: a user manual is usually static content...why using asp.net at all?

Comment: They want it in a way that they can add or remove new segments using an admin panel.

Comment: Adopt an HTML editor - ckedit is a good choice. Thus, they can enter content, and even pictures and screen shots. All your code then is to save, and retrieve the markup and display it.  Left side could be a treeview control.

Comment: For your requriement, you can either choose static site or asp.net core MVC or Razor page app. If the content are dynamic and manual would chnages over the period, you can consider MVC/Razor page, for your manual header, you can include left side navigation which should have anchor link to your details content. First initiate the basic skeleton, and gradually developped, in one shot its hard to explain you all the stuff, when you would start implementing your features, you would face relevant question, just post your issue with your expectation, we will assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Start from something basic. Check some more tutorials and create a WebApp with MVC (you can use Razor if you want) that will have a nav bar and links to jump from one page to another. Most of the youtube MVC tutorials have it. Then add a page with a form in it, play around. Connect the App to database and try to save the text. I am pretty sure this task is for you to learn how to build basic Web Applications. Take your time. Watch a couple of youtube videos on this topic.

https://youtu.be/hZ1DASYd9rk here is a 3 hour long video that does something similar. Of course it is not a web manual for a web app, but you can start from this.